# Parenthsis font should match math and text

Tags: fonts

My `MWE` follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino,mathpazo}
\begin{document}

This is for (test) $(a+b=c)$

\end{document}
```

I am using `PDFLaTeX` for generating the output, and the output generated nicely, but the brackets are in different font in Text and Math mode, please refer the screenshot for better clearence:

[image]

[image]

I required to fix the parenthesis should be in `CMR` font, raising parenthesis, i.e., `\left` and `\right` doesn't matter. Is this possible to fix?

Comment: Why do you require that? You are not using cmr10 for text at all as you have specified T1 encoding, the T1 encoded fonts use the same glyphs as OT1 but are extended to 256 charaters per font with accented letters  etc.

Comment: by the way, those are more usually called "parentheses".  brackets are the square ones `[...]`.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Sorry, now I have updated my question, please suggest...

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks for point out the typo, now corrected...

Comment: surely the brackets in text should be in the text font (otherwise they will look strange when used in non mathematical sentences) and the brackets in math should come from the math font so that they fit in sequence with larger brackets for \big(.

Comment: If for some reason you want to use the text brackets in math use `$\text{(}a+b=c\text{)}$`  (`\text` macro from amsmath, or if not using amsmath use `\mbox`)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks, but my requirement is to fix all parenthesis should be in CMR font globally, is this possible to fix? But it takes more time to give each place \text{(}...and it looks like fully manual...

Comment: you want to use cmr `(` in text even if that text is set in palatino?????

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I meant that text should be in Palatino and all parenthesis (both in Math and Text) should be set in Math font, hope I am clear now...

Comment: If you want the parenthesis from math why not use `$($` rather than `(` that requires no setup at all. It seems a rather odd thing if you just have parenthesis in a text sentence to take them from computer modern if the text is set in palantino. My question in the comment above was not because your requirement was unclear, I was just surprised that you would have such a requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think I properly captured the palatino parens for the extensibles, but it is certainly an improved match relative to the defaults from `mathpazo`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\DeclareMathSymbol{(}{\mathopen}{letters}{`(}
\DeclareMathSymbol{)}{\mathclose}{letters}{`)}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {operators}{"28}{largesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{operators}{"29}{largesymbols}{"01}
\begin{document}

This is for (test) $(a+b=c)$ 

$\bigl(\bigr)$ $\Bigl(\Bigr)$ $\biggl(\biggr)$ $\Biggl(\Biggr)$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For comparison, here it is without my four declarations:

[image]

Comment: This suits with my requirement, thanks a lot...

Comment: Is there any possibility to fix all parenthesis (both text and math) in math font? as per your suggestion, now parenthesis are comes in text font both in Math and text and the raising parenthesis are in Math font...

Comment: @MadyYuvi I am sorry, but I don't know how to readily make the text parens employ the math font, except maybe by way of active characters.  But I would be hesitant to make parens active characters across a whole document.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the same parentheses in Palatino text and math is to find a math font which would match Palatino. I'm not sure there's one for PdfLaTeX, but for XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with `unicode-math` you can use `Asana Math` with the following code:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{URW Palladio L}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\begin{document}

This is for (test) $(a+b=c)$

\end{document}
```

The result seems fine to me:

[image]